# Dot is not added at the end of href

Tags: php, html

My Key is `$P$BeVBjO.GF/Ngju8PCjKJgjV68buIgo.` so you can see a dot at the end of my key

**Input:**

```
esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'loginName' => $requestedUserLogin, 'key' => **$key** ), wppb_curpageurl() ) )
```

**Output:**

```
< **anchor tag** href="http://-------------/lost-password/?submitted=yes&loginName=------&key=$P$BeVBjO.GF/Ngju8PCjKJgjV68buIgo" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">http://-------------/lost-password/?submitted=yes&loginName=------&key=$P$BeVBjO.GF/Ngju8PCjKJgjV68buIgo.<end anchor tag>
```

I am not getting dot at the end of href, but the link text has a dot.

Comment: I have set wp_generate_password( 20, false ) in my plugin now so its not going to generate special and extra special character, but I want to know why this problem occurs ....